# jquery ui - hover over parent element should trigger slide down on child element

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-hover

the problem: hovering above the outer div triggers the expected slide method but not once but multiple times if the mouse is moved inside the outer div. i don't think it's a bubbling issue because the event is bound to the parent element and not to the children. also i prevent the event to "bubble up" by using stopPropagating();

here's the html markup:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Lorem ipsum dol
    <div class="clear"></div></div>
</div><div class="clear"></div>
```

and the css:

```
.outer {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #06F;
}
.inner {
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
    height: 99px;
    background-color: #0F6;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

and the jquery

```
$(".outer").hover(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //$(".inner").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".inner").stop(true, true).hide("slide", {direction: "down"}, "slow");
}, function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //$(".inner").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".inner").stop(true, true).show("slide", {direction: "down"}, "slow");
});
```

the commented code works fine by the way.

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/94hvS/

Comment: add a js fiddle link, it should be easy as you have already isolated your problem part.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this is to use a global boolean variable to know if you're already sliding the object :

```
var sliding = false;
$(".outer").hover(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //$(".inner").fadeOut("slow");
    if(!sliding) {
        sliding = true;
        $(".inner").stop(true, true).hide("slide", {direction: "down"}, "slow", function() { sliding = false; });
    }
}, function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //$(".inner").fadeIn("slow");
    if(!sliding) {
        sliding = true;
        $(".inner").stop(true, true).hide("slide", {direction: "down"}, "slow", function() { sliding = false; });
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if the `function() { sliding = false; }` is in the right place, but it must be called when the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like overlaying `ui-effects-wrapper` (created by slide animation) is resetting your hover state. One thing I can think of would be to simply remember hover state manually in a variable like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/94hvS/1/). Lame, but works.
Not sure if there is more gracious solution.